# MS access project related tasks count on main form

Tags: sql, ms-access, subform

I have two tables in DB
 1. "Projects" -- Main Form
 2. "Tasks"  & two Forms "Projects" & "Tasks" I want to calculate total No. of tasks & show in "Total Tasks" Field in "Projects form"

I check below video but it's not working in my case 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glmdBZOe9u8

Thanks in advance.

--Albertestein

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote please.

Comment: i am placed one text box name is Total Tasks on Projects form and one is txtTotalTasks on Tasks form & insert below expression in control source property of "Total Tasks" text box on projects form.  & expression is   "=[Task].[Form]!txtTotalTasks"......   i think i am wrong to do this.  but please guide me how to do this.